# 2 X-Axis row, 1 Y-Axis Column and 2 Z-Axis Value Pivot Table SQL Server 2008 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server database table like below-

```
id | consignee | shipper | lss | cm1 | month
1  | hnm       | A       | 101 | 25  | Jan
2  | hnm       | B       | 102 | 35  | Jan
3  | hnm       | A       | 103 | 45  | Feb
```

I want to have an output like below-

```
consignee | shipper | Jan       | Feb      |
                    | cm1 | lss | cm1 | lss|
hnm       | A       | 25  | 1   | 45  | 1  |
hnm       | B       | 35  | 1   | 0   | 0  |
```

Here COUNT function is applied on lss and SUM applied on cm1. I don't even know if this is possible in SQL Server query. From what I have seen by searching is people converting rows into columns or 1 X-Axis, 1 Y-Axis and 1 Z-Axis queries, but nothing like this. I can do this easily on Excel using pivot, but I need to get this data from a database like this format and export to a Excel file.

Note: I am working on a ASP .NET application where I am using C# and OleDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. it is possible.

```
SELECT  consignee , shipper ,
        jan_cm1 = MAX (CASE WHEN month = 'Jan' THEN cm1 END),
        jan_lss = MAX (CASE WHEN month = 'Jan' THEN lss END),
        feb_cm1 = MAX (CASE WHEN month = 'Feb' THEN cm1 END),
        feb_lss = MAX (CASE WHEN month = 'Feb' THEN lss END)
FROM    yourtable
GROUP BY consignee , shipper
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I changed MAX with SUM for cm1 and MAX with COUNT for lss, it worked. So I am accepting this as the answer. As a follow up questions, month is actually dynamic. Sometimes there maybe 3 months, sometimes there maybe all 12. Can this query be modified to make it dynamic rather than hard coding the months?